# Possible g++ bug with generic lambda and inheritance

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, c++14

I've reduced as much as possible my use case (which uses variadic template and boost::variant) to the following code:

```
struct A {};

auto l1 = [](A& a){}; // visit A
auto l2 = [](auto& n){n *= 2;};

using t1 = decltype(l1);
using t2 = decltype(l2);

struct overload_set : t1, t2
{
    using t1::operator();
    using t2::operator();

    overload_set() : t1(l1), t2(l2) {}
};

void f()
{
    overload_set visitor;
    double x = 1.1;
    visitor(x);
}
```

See it online here: https://godbolt.org/g/Vrtc2V

That fails with gcc --std=c++14 at least with versions 5.x, 6.x and 7.x (all I could test online), and works with latest gcc 8.0.0 on https://wandbox.org/
Changing the order of inheritance (to inherit first from the generic lambda) does not fix the problem.

It works with clang and VS2015.

Can anyone confirm that this is a gcc bug?
I guess it is a known bug because it seems to have been fixed in gcc. 
Link to bugzilla very appreciated.

The only workaround seems to be to make the lambda non-generic, which is a no-go for my use case.. :(

Thanks!

PS: the unintelligible compiler error is

```
required by substitution of 'template<class auto:1> <lambda(auto:1&)>::operator decltype (((const<lambda(auto:1&)>*)((const<lambda(auto:1&)>* const)0))->operator()(static_cast<auto:1&>(<anonymous>))) (*)(auto:1&)() const [with auto:1 = A]'
required from here
error: no match for 'operator*=' (operand types are 'A' and 'int')
auto l2 = [](auto& n){n *= 2;};
                   ~~^~~~
```